# Sumar valores en un group by MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-by

La situación es que estoy desarrollando un sistema de almuerzos, donde el escenario es el siguiente.

Existen los proveedores, ellos llevaran la comida a diferentes sitios, entonces los clientes pueden pedir su almuerzo en el edificio A, pero tambien pueden pedirlo en el Edificio B a través de este sistema, el valor de la comida varia en los edificios.

1. Edificio A $2.00
2. Edificio B $2.50

Todo esto ya esta desarrollado, el problema es que a final del mes el personal encargado debe cobrar el valor del almuerzo que se ha pedido, entonces elabore un query donde agrupo y saco la cantidad de almuerzos que han pedido todos los clientes.

```
SELECT p.id_colaborador Cliente,  COUNT(DISTINCT p.fecha) Total_Pedidos
FROM pedidos p, proveedor_empresa pm
WHERE p.id_prove_emp=pm.id
AND p.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-30'
GROUP BY p.id_colaborador,DATE_FORMAT(p.fecha, '%M')
ORDER BY p.id_colaborador;
```

Este query me muestra:

| Cliente | Total_Pedidos |
| --- | --- |
| Pepito | 2 |
| Maria | 5 |

Por ahora todo bien, ahora debo calcular ese valor, teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Pepito pidio 1 almuerzo en edifico A y 1 en Edificio B, por lo tanto
   debe sumar $4.50
2. Maria pidio 3 almuerzos en edificio A ($6) y 2 en edifico B ($5),
   que suman $11.00

Entonces modifico el query:

```
SELECT p.id_colaborador Cliente, REPLACE(pm.valor*COUNT(DISTINCT p.fecha),'.',',') Valor
FROM pedidos p, proveedor_empresa pm
WHERE p.id_prove_emp=pm.id
AND p.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-30'
GROUP BY p.id_colaborador,DATE_FORMAT(p.fecha, '%M')
ORDER BY p.id_colaborador;
```

pero me da estos resultados:

| Cliente | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| Pepito | 4.00 |
| Maria | 10.00 |

Es decir, no esta calculando como yo quiero, yo asimilo que cuando multiplico el valor por el numero de pedidos, esta tomando el valor de $2 e ignorando el otro valor, sin embargo ya no tengo ideas de como poder calcularlo correctamente.

Agrego imágen de la relación de las tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ultima aclaración estoy haciendo un **GROUP BY p.id_colaborador,DATE_FORMAT(p.fecha, '%M')**, donde busco que me agrupe los clientes (id_colaborador) y el mes, ya que en la tabla **pedidos** puedo tener algo como:

- Pepito Comida opcion 1  2021-09-01
- Pepito Comida ensalada 1 2021-09-01

Y eso equivale a 1 almuerzo.

Answer (score 0):

Esto `pm.valor*COUNT(DISTINCT p.fecha)` no tiene sentido, además en cualquier base de datos (no quiero decir "seria") menos en mysql te daría un error. Entiendo tu lógica, contar los pedidos que tengo por cada `proveedor_empresa` y lo multiplico por el valor de estos, pero esto tendría sentido si el informe requiere además agrupar por la sede, además, contar las fechas distintas, no necesariamente te cuenta los pedidos, por ejemplo, que pasa si una persona almuerza dos veces, o se imputa el almuerzo de otro compañero, eventualmente para contar un pedido tienes el id del pedido.

En definitiva te estas complicando innecesariamente, o al menos eso es lo que entiendo, si quieres saber el total mensual por colaborador, relaciona cada pedido con `proveedor_empresa` y simplemente suma el valor, también, nunca olvides el año cuando haces consultas mensuales, es fácil que por error te entren datos de un mismo mes pero distinto año.

```
SELECT p.id_colaborador Cliente,
       YEAR(p.fecha)    Year,
       MONTH(p.fecha)   Month,
       SUM(pm.Valor)    Total
       FROM pedidos p
       INNER JOIN proveedor_empresa pm
          ON p.id_prove_emp=pm.id
       WHERE p.fecha BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-30'
       GROUP BY p.id_colaborador,
                YEAR(p.fecha),
                MONTH(p.fecha)
       ORDER BY p.id_colaborador;
```